# Flutter Web Request Header Cookies is not set in request headers

Tags: flutter, dart, http, cookies

I have a Login API which returns Cookies in Response Headers. This cookie value should be passed to subsequent API calls.

Cookies are by default handled by Browser itself in Angular framework but in flutter web it is not getting passed.

I am using http dart package for making API calls. How can we manages cookies in Flutter Web.

```
Future<http.Response> post({
    required String url,
    required dynamic body,
    required Map<String, String> headers,
  }) async {
    headers['cookie'] = _generateCookieHeader();
    try {
      await InternetService.hasAccess;
    } catch (e) {
      print('internet exception --> $e');
      rethrow;
    }
    final client = await getClient;
    http.Response response = await client.post(
      Uri.parse(url),
      body: body,
      headers: headers,
    );
    return response;
  }


String _generateCookieHeader() {
    String cookie = "";
    print("cookie inside");
    for (var key in cookies.keys) {
      if (cookie.isNotEmpty) cookie += ";";
      cookie += "$key=${cookies[key]!}";
    }
    return cookie;
  }
```

Using the above I am trying to set cooking to request header. But in the console getting the error "Refused to set unsafe header 'Cookie'".